# How to secure IAM access key with MFA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I know it is possible to enhance the security by putting another layer (virtual/hardware) MFA over password. Can I secure the access key by MFA.

The problem I am trying to solve is that I would some time commit my access key into github accidentally. so I need a MFA thing for that,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by adding a condition to your IAM policies that requires a recent MFA authentication. For example,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["ec2:*"],
    "Resource": ["*"],
    "Condition": {"NumericLessThan":      {"aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "3600"}}
  }]
}
```

Allows access to the ec2 Apis if you have authenticated with an MFA in the past hour. There are [more examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_example-policies.html) in the docs.

This requires that you call the GetSessionToken api with your credentials and the MFA code and then use the returned temporary credentials for your actual api calls.

If your code is running on EC2 then you should instead use IAM roles - this sets up credentials available on the instance that are rotated every few hours.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just curious, then how can I possible give in the multi-factor key when using aws-cli for example, or the application started holding this access key to connect to the other application.

Comment: For code running on an ec2 instance you should be assigning an IAM role to the instance. Aws cli allows you to get temporary credentials ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html ) which you could then export as environment variables for future calls to aws cli